# VB to C# "valuechanged" syntax

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I am trying to learn C# and am rewriting a small calculator from vb to c#. I have been used to the following with vb:

```
Private Sub nudGKCxCordDiamMM_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nudGKCxCordDiamMM.ValueChanged, nudGKCxPasses.ValueChanged, nudGKCxFacets.ValueChanged, nudGKCxCords.ValueChanged, nudGKCxExtraCord.ValueChanged
```

With the stated above i was able to have the value change between multiple different things for ex: all of the "xxxxxx.valuechanged" listed above in one private sub. How do I write the above in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the events dynamically using "+=" like code below :

```
   public class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            nudGKCxCordDiamMM.ValueChanged += nudGKCxCordDiamMM_ValueChanged;
        }

        private void nudGKCxCordDiamMM_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: _register the events dynamically using_ -  I think you mean _register **manually**_ ;)

Comment: If it is in code it is dynamic.

Comment: Which you should type manually ;)

Comment: Manually would be if you had a form and added the event using the form tools before the code is executed.  He it is dynamic because it is done at run time.

Comment: All the form tools do is add a line of code to the designer code file.  It will still be wired up at runtime.  It's the same thing, really.

Comment: Yes I know.  But I consider that manual because user has to push buttons rather than being a line of code in user module.  How many people actually ever open the designer files?